# Bug ao clicar em Tag sem perguntas não respondidas

Tags: bug, status-intencional

Ao clicar no link da tag que não possua perguntas não respondidas, por exemplo:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-6

Não consigo acessar de forma alguma as informações da tag, como a Wiki, por exemplo. Para acessar a página da tag, preciso clicar primeiro na aba Info, depois clicar no link da tag.

Isso não ocorre para tag que possuam perguntas não respondidas.

Comment: Não entendi, essa tag nem tem wiki!

Comment: @bfavaretto Veja a resposta abaixo. Deve esclarecer melhor.

Comment: Eu li, mas continuo não entendendo. Na tag C, por exemplo, qualquer aba mostra um resumo do wiki no topo. E a aba info mostra o wiki completo. Em tags que não têm wiki, o comportamento é o mesmo, mas com a mensagem de que a tag não tem wiki. Ou eu vejo algo diferente de você por ser moderador, ou entendi mal o problema.

Comment: Eu também não estou captando qual é o problema... Li a resposta, naveguei lá nas tags... No link de exemplo tem lá o linkzinho `saiba mais`, clica-se nele e vai pra página de informações da tag `entity-framework-6`... (?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que entendi o problema.

A URL com `tagged` usada quando você clica numa tag é para uma pesquisa e não para a tag específica.

Por exemplo, a seguinte URL contém duas tags e foi gerada clicando sobre uma e depois sobre outra na sequência:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-6+asp.net-mvc-5

No entanto, o link para as informações da tag é:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/entity-framework-6/info

Este sempre vai para a página correta.

No entanto, quando você clica em qualquer outra aba que não a *Info*, perceba que a URL contém um parâmetro `sort`. Exemplo:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-6?sort=frequent&pageSize=15

Esse parâmetro é armazenado e se você acessar uma URL com `tagged` sem o parâmetro ele vai reusar aquele valor.

Entretanto, isso não funciona para a página `/info` porque não faz parte do mesmo grupo.

Enfim, eu consideraria isso um *by-design*.

Comment: Sim, isso funciona, mas se você clicar na tag na aba "Sem respostas", não vai para a informação da tag, como ocorre normalmente com qualquer outra tag.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Eu *acho* que isso ocorre porque não há informaçoes para a tag...

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Na verdade eu vi que se você clicar em uma aba qualquer ele sempre volta para essa mesma aba, menos para a `Info`.

Comment: Exato. Este é o bug.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Veja a atualização.

Comment: Resumiu bem. Agora, não sei se deve ser colocado mesmo como bug ou não. Eu acho que deve.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Vou ver com o Gabe isso.

Comment: Eu também não entendi o problema :/